# Custom, simple cache with load timeout and expiry; thread safety, tests

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

The following is a code from one of my projects which implements a loading cache with timeout and expiry. The associated tests are [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/msg-simple/master/src/test/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/provider/LoadingMessageSourceProviderTest.java) (mixed with a good number of argument sanity checks tests). I seek comments on the thread safety aspects in particular. I think it is, but I may miss something.

Also, do you see ways it could be improved?

```
/**
 * A caching, on-demand loading message source provider with configurable expiry
 *
 * <p>This class uses a {@link MessageSourceLoader} internally to look up
 * message sources. As is the case for {@link StaticMessageSourceProvider}, you
 * can also set a default source if the loader fails to grab a source.</p>
 *
 * <p>Apart from the loader, you can customize two aspects of the provider:</p>
 *
 * <ul>
 *     <li>its load timeout (5 seconds by default);</li>
 *     <li>its expiry time (10 minutes by default).</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>Note that the expiry time is periodic only, and not per source. The
 * loading result (success or failure) is recorded permanently until the expiry
 * time kicks in, <b>except</b> when the timeout kicks in; in this case, loading
 * will be retried.</p>
 *
 * <p>You cannot instantiate that class directly; use {@link #newBuilder()} to
 * obtain a builder class and set up your provider.</p>
 */
@ThreadSafe
public final class LoadingMessageSourceProvider
    implements MessageSourceProvider
{
    /*
     * Use daemon threads. We don't give control to the user about the
     * ExecutorService, and we don't have a reliable way to shut it down (a JVM
     * shutdown hook does not get involved on a webapp shutdown, so we cannot
     * use that...).
     */
    private static final ThreadFactory THREAD_FACTORY = new ThreadFactory()
    {
        private final ThreadFactory factory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(final Runnable r)
        {
            final Thread ret = factory.newThread(r);
            ret.setDaemon(true);
            return ret;
        }
    };

    private static final InternalBundle BUNDLE
        = InternalBundle.getInstance();

    private static final int NTHREADS = 3;

    /*
     * Executor service for loading tasks
     */
    private final ExecutorService service
        = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS, THREAD_FACTORY);

    /*
     * Loader and default source
     */
    private final MessageSourceLoader loader;
    private final MessageSource defaultSource;

    /*
     * Timeout
     */
    private final long timeoutDuration;
    private final TimeUnit timeoutUnit;

    /*
     * List of sources
     */
    private final Map<Locale, FutureTask<MessageSource>> sources
        = new HashMap<Locale, FutureTask<MessageSource>>();

    private LoadingMessageSourceProvider(final Builder builder)
    {
        loader = builder.loader;
        defaultSource = builder.defaultSource;
        timeoutDuration = builder.timeoutDuration;
        timeoutUnit = builder.timeoutUnit;
        if (builder.expiryDuration > 0L)
            setupExpiry(builder.expiryDuration, builder.expiryUnit);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new builder
     *
     * @return an empty builder
     */
    public static Builder newBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Override
    public MessageSource getMessageSource(final Locale locale)
    {
        FutureTask<MessageSource> task;

        /*
         * The algorithm is as follows:
         *
         * - access the sources map in a synchronous manner (the expiry task
         *   also does this);
         * - grab the FutureTask matching the required locale:
         *     - if no task exists, create it;
         *     - if it exists but has been cancelled (in the event of a timeout,
         *       see below), create a new task;
         * - always within the synchronized access to sources, submit the task
         *   for immediate execution to our ExecutorService;
         * - to be followed...
         */
        synchronized (sources) {
            task = sources.get(locale);
            if (task == null || task.isCancelled()) {
                task = loadingTask(locale);
                sources.put(locale, task);
                service.execute(task);
            }
        }

        /*
         * - try and get the result of the task, with a timeout;
         * - if we get a result in time, return it, or the default source (if
         *   any) if the result is null;
         * - in the event of an error, return the default source; in addition,
         *   if this is a timeout, cancel the task.
         */
        try {
            final MessageSource source = task.get(timeoutDuration, timeoutUnit);
            return source == null ? defaultSource : source;
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            return defaultSource;
        } catch (ExecutionException ignored) {
            return defaultSource;
        } catch (TimeoutException ignored) {
            task.cancel(true);
            return defaultSource;
        }
    }

    private FutureTask<MessageSource> loadingTask(final Locale locale)
    {
        return new FutureTask<MessageSource>(new Callable<MessageSource>()
        {
            @Override
            public MessageSource call()
                throws IOException
            {
                return loader.load(locale);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupExpiry(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
    {
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                /*
                 * We need to walk the list of current tasks and cancel them if
                 * they are still running.
                 */
                synchronized (sources) {
                    /*
                     * This MUST be done from within this block. If we don't do
                     * this here, a task can "leak" from getMessageSource(), and
                     * if the caller .get()s, it will be greeted with a
                     * CancellationException. Not what we want!
                     */
                    for (final FutureTask<MessageSource> task: sources.values())
                        task.cancel(true);
                    sources.clear();
                }
            }
        };
        // Overkill?
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduled
            = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, THREAD_FACTORY);
        final long initialDelay = unit.toMillis(duration);
        scheduled.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, initialDelay, duration, unit);
    }

    /**
     * Builder class for a {@link LoadingMessageSourceProvider}
     */
    public static final class Builder
    {
        private MessageSourceLoader loader;
        private MessageSource defaultSource;
        private long timeoutDuration = 5L;
        private TimeUnit timeoutUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
        private long expiryDuration = 10L;
        private TimeUnit expiryUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;

        private Builder()
        {
        }

        /**
         * Set the message source loader
         *
         * @param loader the loader
         * @throws NullPointerException loader is null
         * @return this
         */
        public Builder setLoader(final MessageSourceLoader loader)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(loader, "cfg.nullLoader");
            this.loader = loader;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the default message source if the loader fails to load
         *
         * @param defaultSource the default source
         * @throws NullPointerException source is null
         * @return this
         */
        public Builder setDefaultSource(final MessageSource defaultSource)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(defaultSource, "cfg.nullDefaultSource");
            this.defaultSource = defaultSource;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the load timeout
         *
         * @param duration number of units
         * @param unit the time unit
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException {@code duration} is negative or zero
         * @throws NullPointerException {@code unit} is null
         * @return this
         *
         * @deprecated use {@link #setLoadTimeout(long, TimeUnit)} instead.
         * Will be removed in 0.6.
         */
        @Deprecated
        public Builder setTimeout(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(duration > 0L, "cfg.nonPositiveDuration");
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(unit, "cfg.nullTimeUnit");
            timeoutDuration = duration;
            timeoutUnit = unit;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the load timeout (5 seconds by default)
         *
         * <p>If the loader passed as an argument fails to load a message
         * source after the specified timeout is elapsed, then the default
         * messagesource will be returned (if any).</p>
         *
         * @param duration number of units
         * @param unit the time unit
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException {@code duration} is negative or zero
         * @throws NullPointerException {@code unit} is null
         * @return this
         *
         * @see {@link #setLoader(MessageSourceLoader)}
         * @see {@link #setDefaultSource(MessageSource)}
         */
        public Builder setLoadTimeout(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(duration > 0L, "cfg.nonPositiveDuration");
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(unit, "cfg.nullTimeUnit");
            timeoutDuration = duration;
            timeoutUnit = unit;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the source expiry time (10 minutes by default)
         *
         * <p>Do <b>not</b> use this method if you want no expiry at all; use
         * {@link #neverExpires()} instead.</p>
         *
         * @since 0.5
         *
         * @param duration number of units
         * @param unit the time unit
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException {@code duration} is negative or zero
         * @throws NullPointerException {@code unit} is null
         * @return this
         */
        public Builder setExpiryTime(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit)
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(duration > 0L, "cfg.nonPositiveDuration");
            BUNDLE.checkNotNull(unit, "cfg.nullTimeUnit");
            expiryDuration = duration;
            expiryUnit = unit;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set this loading provider so that entries never expire
         *
         * <p>Note that, as noted in the description, apart from loading
         * timeouts, successes and failures are recorded permanently (see
         * {@link FutureTask}).</p>
         *
         * @since 0.5
         *
         * @return this
         */
        public Builder neverExpires()
        {
            expiryDuration = 0L;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Build the provider
         *
         * @return a {@link LoadingMessageSourceProvider}
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException no loader has been provided
         */
        public MessageSourceProvider build()
        {
            BUNDLE.checkArgument(loader != null, "cfg.noLoader");
            return new LoadingMessageSourceProvider(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just 2 comments: (i) Technically (although unlikely), `sources` could be `null` in `setupExpiry` as your constructor has not completed yet. (ii) In case of InterruptedException, you could probably reinterrupt `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()`, as a courtesy to the calling code.

Comment: @assylias (as to sources) really? Uh! How is that possible? (as to interrupting) I am not sure I am following you here? I catch `InterruptedException` here as a possible result of the `FutureTask`'s `.get()` call

Comment: It is possible that the scheduled thread starts before your constructor finishes (unlikely but possible). If that happens, `sources` might not be initialised yet.

Comment: In "your code", you mean the `Callable` in `Future` or the call to `.getMessageSource()`?

Comment: You are right, only you have access to the ExecutorService and the tasks so an interruption would come from your class and you can ignore it. My mistake.

Comment: @assylias You're actually right. The client calling `getMessageSource()` is blocking on the `Future.get()`. If that client is interrupted, the interrupted flag is not set when exiting `getMessageSource()` and the client will not know it got interrupted, and needs to clean up. Proper solution here seems to simply add InterruptedException to the method signature : clients have a right to know they're calling a blocking method.

Comment: @bowmore uh, I'd like to avoid that if I can :/ Is there a way to distinguish between the future raising it or the client actually being interrupted? If I add the exception to the signature, this also means I have to add the exception on _all_ the call chain (given that the library provides log messages, that is rather a pain!)

Comment: How would the Future raise it?

Comment: @bowmore uh OK, that is a brain fart from my part :/ So, basically, I `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` before I return the value and that should be OK?

Comment: That would be ok, but it's probably better to let clients know they're calling a blocking method and add InterruptedException to the method sig, and not catch it yourself.

Comment: Well, this is a message provider API, the end user calls `.getMessage()` from another class, not this method. And there are providers which are static and can therefore not throw that exception, except on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do have a race condition. The test below should expose it.

```
@Mock
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Test
public void testExpiryDuringLoadingDoesNotInterfereWithGetMessageSourceCallInProgress() throws Exception {

    MessageSourceProvider sourceProvider = LoadingMessageSourceProvider.newBuilder().setExpiryTime(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setDefaultSource(messageSource).setLoader(new SlowLoader())
            .build();
    MessageSource messageSource = sourceProvider.getMessageSource(Locale.CHINA);
    assertThat(messageSource).isEqualTo(messageSource);
}

private class SlowLoader implements MessageSourceLoader {
    @Override
    public MessageSource load(Locale locale) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

While I force the race condition to fail in the test by making the expiry time really short, and the loading time long, that is in itself not a necessary condition.

Here's the code relevant snippet with added comments :

```
synchronized (sources) {                // cannot clean up here
    task = sources.get(locale);
    if (task == null || task.isCancelled()) {
        task = loadingTask(locale);
        sources.put(locale, task);
        service.execute(task);
    }
}
                                        // yet here it can : task cancellation may happen during cleanup here
                                        // expiry may have been imminent just before the resource was requested
try {
    final MessageSource source = task.get(timeoutDuration, timeoutUnit); // load may even be short : cancelation could have happened even before this request.
    return source == null ? defaultSource : source;
```

Comment: I think you're right... I'll reproduce. This can happen if the load timeout is _more_ than the expiry time, which right now I don't disallow. Duh.

Comment: By the way, you can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);` ;)

Comment: Spot on! I did reproduce...

Comment: Added some more clarification to my answer to show that it isn't necessarily tied to load vs expiry times.

Comment: Yup, after I analyzed it I figured out it was deeper than what I initially surmised. Thanks a LOT for noticing this one!